# Python regex to get string in front of hyphen and plus signs

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a string as shown in the code. I want to get the final result as: ['AA', 'BB','CC'].
But what I have got here is ['AA', 'BB']. Could you please give me some suggestion? Thank you.

```
s = "AA-ZZ, BB+ZZ, CC"
a =  re.findall(r'(\w+)[-|\\+\\]\w',s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lookahead to see whether the string is in front of `+`, `-` or at the `end of string`.

```
a =  re.findall(r'(\w+)(?=[-+]|$)',s)
```